# Need all Regex matches, not just first one

Tags: ruby

This is my string...

```
[foo-1 param1 : value1, param2 : value2]
[foo-2 param1 : value1, param2 : value2, params3 : value3]
...
```

My purpose here is to get all the sequence between [ ] firstly and then to parse all the params. I wrote 2 regex for that, the first one is supposed to get all the sequence between [] :

```
/\[([\w-]+)\s?([\w@.,:\s]*)\]/m
```

The second regex should parse all my parameters

```
/([\w]+)\s?,?:\s?,?([\w@.-]+)/m
```

My problem is that I'm always getting the first match but I'd like to get all the matches.
I tried to do this :

```
r = /\[([\w-]+)\s?([\w@.,:\s]*)\]/m
str = "[foo-1 param1 : value1, param2 : value2]
[foo-2 param1 : value1, param2 : value2, params3 : value3]"

m = r.match(str)

# #<MatchData "[foo-1 param1 : value1, param2 : value2]" 1:"foo-1" 2:"param1 : value1, param2 : value2">
```

Can anybody help me and explain me why my regex is only getting the first match even if there are more matches supposed ? I test it on rubular (here :  http://www.rubular.com/r/nTVE6M5om5) and it seems that it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you are using `Regexp#match`. That only matches once. If you want multiple matches, use `String#scan`.

Comment: So obvious... Thanks ! Short answer but it was what I needed.